# Exception breakpoints with PhpStorm Xdebug & docker

Tags: phpstorm, xdebug, xdebug-3

I am working on WSL2 with PhpStorm, Docker and Xdebug 3.

My line breakpoints are working fine but exception breakpoints don't trigger any break. I have no idea why this fails.

Is any additional configuration required compared to line breakpoints?

[image]

Comment: No additional configuration is required. What if you throw a notice like `user_error(E_NOTICE);`, would it stop? If not, it makes sense to check your [Xdebug log](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/troubleshooting-php-debugging.html#collect-xdebug-logs) contents

Answer (score 0):

The only exception breakpoint that you have set up here, is the one for `Notice`, and not for anything else.

If you want to break on all exceptions, use `*` instead of `Notice` as value, or otherwise a class or interface name of the top level exception that you want to catch.